# How can I select unique rows in a database over two columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have found similar solutions online but none that I've been able to apply to my specific problem.

I'm trying to "unique-ify" data from one table to another. In my original table, data looks like the following:

```
USERIDP1    USERIDP2     QUALIFIER     DATA
1           2            TRUE          AB
1           2                          CD
1           3                          EF
1           3                          GH
```

The user IDs are composed of two parts, USERIDP1 and USERIDP2 concatenated. I want to transfer all the rows that correspond to a user who has QUALIFIER=TRUE in ANY row they own, but ignore users who do not have a TRUE QUALIFIER in any of their rows.

To clarify, all of User 12's rows would be transferred, but not User 13's. The output would then look like:

```
USERIDP1    USERIDP2     QUALIFIER     DATA
1           2            TRUE          AB
1           2                          CD
```

So basically, I need to find rows with distinct user ID components (involving two unique fields) that also possess a row with QUALIFIER=TRUE and copy all and only all of those users' rows.

Comment: For each (useridp1, useridp2) combination, can there be more than one row having qualifier=True?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although this nested query will be very slow for large tables, this could do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.USERIDP1, X.USERIDP2, X.QUALIFIER, X.DATA
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME AS X
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME AS Y WHERE Y.USERIDP1 = X.USERIDP1
              AND Y.USERIDP2 = X.USERIDP2 AND Y.QUALIFIER = TRUE)
```

It could be written as an inner join with itself too:

```
SELECT DISTINCT X.USERIDP1, X.USERIDP2, X.QUALIFIER, X.DATA
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME AS X
INNER JOIN YOUR_TABLE_NAME AS Y ON Y.USERIDP1 = X.USERIDP1
                                AND Y.USERIDP2 = X.USERIDP2 AND Y.QUALIFIER = TRUE
```

For a large table, create a new auxiliary table containing only USERIDP1 and USERIDP2 columns for rows that have QUALIFIER = TRUE and then join this table with your original table using inner join similar to the second option above. Remember to create appropriate indexes.

Comment: Damn, this is exactly what I was hoping would not happen. I have about 80-ish million entries in this table. :( Do you think there are any faster ways to do this?

Comment: Try the inner join... should be pretty fast if indexes exist on IDS & qualifier.

Comment: agreed - the inner join will be a lot faster.

Comment: Hmm, what if there are more columns and I want to retrieve them all? This solution only retrieves the four columns above, but my table has 80-odd columns, all of which I'd like to export (but still using the rules above).

Comment: Just add them in the select after X.DATA separated by commas

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick - if the id fields are stored as integers then you will need to convert / cast into Varchars

```
SELECT 1 as id1,2 as id2,'TRUE' as qualifier,'AB' as data into #sampled
UNION ALL SELECT 1,2,NULL,'CD' 
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3,NULL,'EF'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,3,NULL,'GH'

   ;WITH data as
    (
    SELECT
    id1 
    ,id2 
    ,qualifier
    ,data
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN qualifier = 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY id1 + '' + id2) as num_qualifier
    from #sampled
    )
    SELECT 
    id1
    ,id2
    ,qualifier
    ,data
    from data
    where num_qualifier > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from yourTable
INNER JOIN (Select UserIDP1, UserIDP2 FROM yourTable WHERE Qualifier=TRUE) B
ON yourTable.UserIDP1 = B.UserIDP1 and YourTable.UserIDP2 = B.UserIDP2
```

Comment: Won't this duplicate some rows if multiple members of an (id1, id2) group have qualifier=TRUE?

Comment: Yes it could. I would need to add a distinct or group by to the inner join but I don't see that example or statement in the information provided. (anyway I already agreed with christian's 2nd solution being faster)

Answer (score 0):

How about a subquery as a where clause?

```
SELECT *
  FROM theTable t1
 WHERE CAST(t1.useridp1 AS VARCHAR) + CAST(t1.useridp2 AS VARCHAR) IN
         (SELECT CAST(t2.useridp1 AS VARCHAR) + CAST(t.useridp2 AS VARCHAR)
            FROM theTable t2
           WHERE t2.qualified
         );
```

Comment: Ugh, no, this is a crap way to do it. use the inner join method.

Comment: For the sake of me learning, what's wrong with this solution?

Comment: It's just slow... I believe it will work, but it's totally untested - I don't have an sql server instance nearby anymore to test on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution in mysql, but I believe it should transfer to sql server pretty easily.  Use a subquery to pick out groups of (id1, id2) combinations with at least one True 'qualifier' row; then join that to the original table on (id1, id2).

```
mysql> SELECT u1.*
       FROM users u1
       JOIN (SELECT id1,id2
             FROM users
             WHERE qualifier
             GROUP BY id1, id2) u2
       USING(id1, id2);

+------+------+-----------+------+
| id1  | id2  | qualifier | data |
+------+------+-----------+------+
|    1 |    2 |         1 | aa   |
|    1 |    2 |         0 | bb   |
+------+------+-----------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```